Cycles rendering OpenExr as white blank image
I rendered a lot of projects using Cycles in .png format and now wanted to try using and OpenExr format but all of my renders are coming out as blank white images, whole animation came like that. In viewport everything is ok and in .png also it came well, problem is with OpenExr and I tried to render with passes and without them and results were the same.
Blend file :
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pCJFLaYGZzUWycTRkFOYBXXz6CW-BvlG?usp=sharing
Thanks for all help!

Please don't ask the same question multiple times. Your previous question was closed due to lack of detail, editing it to add the required info would have queued it for reopening review. Secondly, Please always be mindful of how big your blend is. 1.25GB is definitely overkill, most of that data isn't needed to showcase the issue, but downloading that file requires quite a lot of time or money to pay a beefy network bandwidth. Please see the file sharing guide for next time you need to share a file, it explains a lot of useful things.

Your exposure is set to -6 in the color management settings so it's +6 when you open it without that setting.

Adjust the exposure(and other color managements settings) accordingly when you open the EXR files and you will see the same as in the file you render.

Extra info: ignoring Blender's color management is specific to EXR, and here's why

I have no idea why Troy says it's an "unfortunate design decision". I think it's nice because you can always know what is going on if you save as EXR. It will not be changed by color management. That makes things simple. OK, so that's not so amazing if you don't know where the EXR comes from and what the "scene-linear image data" is, but we do know that in case of Blender. That's linear color space with Rec. 709 chromaticities and D65 white point. It could be less hidden in the manual though...
